# NamedTemporaryFile triggers SuspiciousFileOperation

Tags: django

In django version 3.2.12, I try to download an image for which I have an URL and store it inside an ImageField. It looks like this:

```
def load_image_from_url(self):
    image_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True, dir='project/media')
    with urlopen(self.extra_large_url) as uo:
        assert uo.status == 200
        image_file.write(uo.read())
        image_file.flush()
    image = File(image_file)
    self.image.save(image.name, image)
```

When I create the NamedTemporaryFile, the path generated is an absolute path.

In django.core.files.utils, it get blocked in this condition:

```
if allow_relative_path:
    # Use PurePosixPath() because this branch is checked only in
    # FileField.generate_filename() where all file paths are expected to be
    # Unix style (with forward slashes).
    path = pathlib.PurePosixPath(name)
    if path.is_absolute() or '..' in path.parts:
        raise SuspiciousFileOperation(
            "Detected path traversal attempt in '%s'" % name
        )
```

With a dir argument set for the NamedTemporaryFile, the issue remains even if the folder is a subdirectory of the project.

Is there a better solution than doing this:

```
    self.image.save(os.path.basename(image.name), image)
```